# Error in computing gradients in keras(tensorflow backend)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient

I am trying to compute gradients of one of CNN filters from VGG16 w.r.t an image input using tensorflow-gpu version 2.4.1 and Keras version 2.4.3 with the following code:

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import backend as K
model = VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', 
             include_top = False)
layer_name = 'block3_conv1'
filter_index = 0
layer_output = model.get_layer(layer_name).output
loss = K.mean(layer_output[:, :, :, filter_index])

grads = K.gradients(loss, model.input)[0]
```

this results in the following error:

> RuntimeError: tf.gradients is not supported when eager execution is enabled. Use tf.GradientTape instead.

Also trying to use `tf.GradientTape` raised another error:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as gtape:
    grads = gtape.gradient(loss, model.input)
```

> AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute '_id'

trying to disable eager execution did not work either:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

since it returns gradients as None.
I would appreciate any kind of information about any way to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you try the latest one https://keras.io/examples/vision/visualizing_what_convnets_learn/

Comment: Might sounds stupid, but try to replace all the keras by tf.keras in your imports. then go by tf.GradientTape

Answer (score 1):

Let `layer = model.get_layer(layer_name)`

First, you need to construct the model graph

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
heatmap_model = models.Model([model.inputs],[layer.output,model.output])
```

Then you need to run `tf.GradientTape()`

```
with tf.GradientTape() as gtape:
  layer_output, predictions = heatmap_model(img)
  loss = predictions[:,np.argmax(predictions)] 
  grads = gtape.gradient(loss, layer_output)
```

Note that `gtape.gradient` has `layer_output` instead of `layer.output`